# Using Transform Module during MLCP Ingestion to MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am trying to implement envelope pattern when i am ingesting documents through MLCP

My transform Module is like this :

```
function envelope(content, context)
{
  var transformed ={};
  transformed.Metadata = { "Created" : "Time"};
  transformed.Source = content.value;
  content.uri = fn.concat("/transformed/",content.uri);
  content.value = transformed;
};
exports.transform = envelope;
```

My MLCP Command is like this

```
    mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin -
password admin -mode local -input_file_path D:\Marklogic\abcd.csv -input_file_ty
pe delimited_text -document_type json -transform_module /example/
mlcp-transform.sjs -transform_function transform -output_collections transformed -ge
nerate_uri true
```

MLCP Error :

```
    18/01/31 09:00:27 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: Failed document /D:/Marklogi
c/test.pcr-0-9
18/01/31 09:00:27 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: TypeError: Cannot read prope
rty 'uri' of undefined
18/01/31 09:00:27 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: TypeError: Cannot read prope
rty 'uri' of undefined
```

I don't know why it cant able to read the `uri` in my transform module.
Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLCP expects the transform function to return an the updated `content` argument. Try the following:

```
function envelope(content, context)
{
  var transformed ={};
  transformed.Metadata = { "Created" : "Time"};
  transformed.Source = content.value;
  content.uri = fn.concat("/transformed/",content.uri);
  content.value = transformed;
  return content;
};
exports.transform = envelope;
```

Provide target collection names with the `-output_collections` parameter. You can also prefix uri with `/transformed/` using the `-output_uri_prefix`, or the `-output_uri_replace` parameter.

You can find documentation about command-line options here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_23879

Documentation about MLCP transforms can be found here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @grtjn , tried your transform module snippet but getting same error again.

Comment: Auch, forgot to add the `return content` at the end of the function. I updated the answer..